# how to reset form inputs after they are submitted in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

so i have this code(not in details)

```
<p:tabView id="tabviewId">
<p:tab>
<h:form id="mainHeadOfAccountsId_form">
// some input fields with validation
// using viewscoped
<p:commandButton value="Add" process="mainHeadOfAccountsId_form" update="mainHeadOfAccountsId_form :#{p:component('allMainHeadOfAccountsId_table')} :#{p:component('successfullySavedUpdatedId_growl')}" action="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.addMainHeadOfAccountsOnAjax}" />

/// also using <p:datatable id= "allMainHeadOfAccountsId_table" >
</h:form
</p:tab>

<p:tab>
<h:form>
</h:form
</p:tab>

</p:tabView>
<p:growl id="successfullySavedUpdatedId_growl" for="successfullySavedUpdatedFor_growl" value="error" showDetail="false" />
```

my Question is that when i submit form `mainHeadOfAccountsId_form` successfully i need to update(reset) all fields which are in `mainHeadOfAccountsId_form`
but remember that i am also using `<h:selectOneMenu>` so i want to reset(option[0] selected) not empty, how can i do that ? currently its updating `allMainHeadOfAccountsId_table` and `successfullySavedUpdatedId_growl` except `mainHeadOfAccountsId_form`
i have tired `tabviewId:mainHeadOfAccountsId_form` but getting exception component not found,
as i am thinking this is just because of `@viewScoped` and i should reset value of those inputs in my action class (.java), m i right ?

Comment: You're definitely right. `@ViewScoped` bean is keeping your submited values. You have two choices, reset them manually when action method happens or go with `@RequestScoped` bean, which will be recreated once you submit de form.

Comment: @XtremeBiker can you guide me manual way ? i don't want to use `@RequestScoped` bean.

Comment: Sorry but your code looks illegible for me. When submiting the form, you have to initialize every single value you want manually (setting it `null` or the value you want). Then, update only the components you're interested in or the whole form.

Answer (score 0):

see what primefaces offer for [reset input](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf) or after submitting the form by the action in the bean reset the values by new or null and recreate the list held by

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
```